# Is it wrong for my boss to tell my parents what I do wrong in the workplace?

Tags: privacy

My boss keeps telling my parents the things I do wrong at work so not only do I get in trouble at work I get in trouble at home too. Is there any way I can prove that this is wrong and that she can not tell my parents what goes on in the workplace? I’m also 18 by the way.

Comment: Are you still in high school?  It seems like you need to move out and change jobs ASAP.  This is ridiculous.

Comment: Do you have any idea _why_ your boss is doing this? Do your boss and your parents know each other, perhaps?

Comment: At what age do you become a legal adult in your country? How does your boss contact your parents? What specifically did you do wrong? Was it fixable, did you cause bigger financial problems?

Comment: can you please state what country/culture you are in? What is the relationship between your boss and your parents? (Germany - here the boss does not usually have contact data from his employees parents and it would be illegal to do what your boss does)

Comment: I'm surprised by the close votes on this. I don't think this is a bad question. Sure it could use more elaboration: demographics, examples, etc. But I don't think it's unclear what OP is asking for, and I don't think this is opinion based. It might be subjective, but in a good-subjective-bad-subjective kind of way, and the answers would definitely fall on the good side.

Comment: Are your parents and your boss friends? How are you getting into trouble?

Comment: @corsiKa I am surprised you don't think this question is not unclear. How did the boss know the OP's parents' phone number? Does the boss know the OP's parents? What did the boss think the OP was doing wrong? What did the OP do so the boss would call the OP's parents? Did the OP's parents organize the OP's job by using the friendship of the OP's boss (if there is any?) Where is the OP's location? (In my location, some parent accompany their children to interview even the children are college graduates)

Comment: @scaaahu While those details might help an answer be incrementally better, they don't fundamentally change what an answer is likely to be (with the sole possible exception of where they're from...)

Comment: @corsiKa Of course they do. If the boss does not know the OP's parents, he has no business with telling how the OP performs in the workplace. If the boss is a very good friend of the parents', then a good friend telling the parents that their child is in trouble is normal

Comment: @corsika I don't get why you are questioning the close votes and then backpedaling with "sole exceptions". That sole exception is enough of a reason to put the question on hold until the necessary information is available. That aside, it is hardly the "sole exception". The exact nature of the "wrong" the OP was found doing can also influence the answer. For example, if the OP was going home early claiming to be sick far too often, the boss might want to check with the parents if the OP has serious health issues or is just making it up.

Comment: @MaskedMan That reason is enough to close a question? You so you know of other questions that have been closed *only* because OP didn't put a location? I find that *very* hard to believe. And it wouldn't change the answer much. I don't see why people demand that everyone has to write an essay for every question. Boss is speaking when he shouldn't. What can be done about it? The other details **don't really matter**!

Comment: @corsiKa There have been plenty of questions put on hold pending clarification from the OP regarding their location. *"Boss is speaking when he shouldn't."* That is a big assumption you are making. There is nothing in the question to conclude that the boss shouldn't be speaking what he did. *"And it wouldn't change the answer much."* The whole world doesn't work the same way as North America does, by the way.

Comment: It's not a big assumption. It's right there in the question! OP firmly believes this should not be happening, and I cannot imagine a scenario where it's appropriate for a manager to discuss employee relations with the employee's parents. That's not a North America thing, that's a professionalism thing.

Comment: If the OP "firmly believed" this should not be happening, why do they start their question with "is it wrong"? Just because *you* cannot imagine a scenario doesn't mean it doesn't exist, and the definition of "professionalism" varies from one country to another.

Answer (score 37):

This is why it's best not to get a job organised by your parents or where your parents and the boss know each other well enough to do this.

It's actually a failing on both parts, possibly well meant but a failing nethertheless. Your boss shouldn't be telling tales, and your parents shouldn't be listening to them.

All you can do is ask the boss to desist while you're looking for a new job. Or just soldier on until you can leave.

Comment: While the answer is good, no where in the OP it states the relationship between the boss and parents.

Comment: @Dan The OP states that the boss tells the parents about what the OP does at work, which sort of implies that the boss knows the parents. Do you have any other explanation for how the boss can talk to the OP's parents without knowing them?

Answer (score 8):

This must be a frustrating and embarrassing situation for you, even without knowing any of the details as to why or how your boss is talking to your parents. That being said, depending where you are in the world, it is highly unlikely that there will be any local laws to support your situation.

My recommendation is to calmly discuss this with your boss. Explain how their "chats" are effecting your relationships at home negatively.

Depending on how this conversation goes and your boss's reaction, will determine your next move to either stay or look for other work. Hope this helps. Best of luck. T

Comment: In what Jurisdiction are you? I would say it is highly likely there *are* laws to prevent this. Here in Europe: Protection of personal data and also depending on content, slander come to mind ...

Comment: @Daniel the content of what is conveyed from boss to parent is obviously determinative of whether a legal wrong has been committed. But from what OP has posted, it sounds more like the boss is telling the parents about OP's actions (that's not defamation in the usual sense if it is truthful). If it's actions (and not things like medical claims or other protected info), then it's rather unlikely that a law has been breached.  If OP was lazy at work, and Boss told Parents (facts only), then what legal wrong would you identity?  It's poor behavior by all, but illegal?

Comment: Even if this could somehow be solved legally, it sounds unnecessarily expensive at best. At worst, it completely destroys the relationships of any people involved.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you're American and your parents have classic American views on teen work.

That being said, it seems like a no-brainer to have your parents give you the easy job hook up. Who wants to interview and risk rejection?!

As you can see, it comes with caveats.

I agree with others that this is a failing on behalf of both parents and employer. They aren't giving you the respect of a young adult and encouraging you to be responsible for yourself. There is another problem here too: you're vulnerable to abuse by your employer if your parents aren't respecting you as an adult. I don't know your age or you're gender, but imagine a circumstance where your boss sexually assaults you: if you can't turn to your parents then who can you turn to?

The only way out is thusly (and this too will require you to have uncomfortable conversations but establish yourself and an adult):

To your parents: express your gratitude for their help and then bluntly tell them it's now your opportunity to lose. The chatter between them and your boss is not giving you the room to learn to be an adult and it needs to end. You will need to speak sternly but respectfully; assert your need to grow. They may ultimately say really discouraging things like it's their reputation and you're embarrassing them ( some parents are dicks like that). Be ready to hear it. Kids are always an extension of the parents even when you're grown. But that doesn't mean they have a right to hurt you with it.

To your employer: be blunt and tell him the job is between him and you and no one else and you need him to respect that. If he can't you will need to move on.

Be ready to quit or be fired in some unceremonious fashion. Be ready for all of them to ignore your request and continue to treat you like a child. If they don't get in line, quit (with notice even if they send you packing on the spot).

You will feel humiliated. Remember that sting and don't repeat the mistake.

Comment: "*If you can't turn to your parents, who can you turn to?*" -- I'd just like to point out that the police exist, especially in America. If you've been sexually assaulted, no matter by who, you can _always_ (and, IMO, should always, though that can be extremely difficult in the moment) go to the police and report it. And if your parents won't support you through _being assaulted_, then they can get [censored]; at 18 you're no longer legally required to obey them and you can cut them out of your life as soon as you're stable on your own. I agree with the rest of this answer, though.

Comment: " it seems like a no-brainer to have your parents give you the easy job hook up" Did I miss something in the question where it was stated that the OP got this job because of a reference or connection their parents had?

Comment: @NicHartley, if you think the police are a viable option if you have been sexually assaulted, then you are sadly mistaken. Women don't report this to the police because they usually make it worse by assuming you are a slut who deserved it. Trust me very few women go to the police and of the ones I know who have, ALL regretted doing so.

Comment: Yeah, the police - who doesn't like being doubted and looked at like you're in the wrong when you try to do your due dilligence and report crimes?

Comment: If you thought the poster had a difficult situation to manage now, wait until you report your employer ( and parents friends?) To the police. The system is stacked against kids. Deference is always given to parents without grotesque visible signs of abuse. Saying that you are no longer obligated to obey your parents at 18 and that you can leave whenever you're "able" is contradictory and neieve. They likely own your car, control much of your money and still can manipulate your life. They is an enormous power advantage to parents that doesn't just vanish at 18

Comment: @HLGEM You know, that's entirely fair, and not something I considered. Probably because I know a few cops who have dealt with sexual assault cases and _not_ done that but, in retrospect, the few cops I know probably aren't representative of the general population. Small sample sizes and all that.

Comment: You have slid far too much on the slippery slope here. "My boss tells things I do wrong at work to my parents" doesn't lead to "What if your boss sexually assaults you?" by any stretch of imagination.

Comment: I said that lack of parental support makes you vulnerable. I didn't say the person would do anything ever or imminently.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to look at this from another angle.

In most work places, bosses would just fire you instead of talking to your parents. I'm assuming that your boss is friends with your parents. Perhaps he doesn't feel comfortable firing you so he tries talking to your parents. You said you get into trouble both at work and at home, so I'm assuming your boss is talking to you about the issues as well.

The way I see it, you need to ask yourself this question: "Do I want this job?"

If the answer is no, then quit. Find something better, explain to your parents about your feelings, and (very important!) thank your boss for giving you this opportunity.

If the answer is yes, then you need to figure out why you keep getting into trouble at work. Your boss is likely talking to your parents because talking to you isn't getting any results. Any other boss would likely have just let you go by now. You need to figure out what you're doing wrong and fix it. Sit down with your boss and talk to him about it. I bet that if your boss can resolve those issues with you, he will not be going to your parents anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are 18 and thus an adult... I would say it is not wrong, it is illegal.

Your work contract has an expectation of privacy for work related matters and given that your parents are not priviledged anymore. Internal Company Affairs are confidential by law - at least in most countries.

Comment: Do you have any references regarding the idea that workplace matters are confidential "in most countries"?  Proprietary products and methods may be confidential, but "hey, Alyssa'a parents, I thought you should know that Alyssa is always checking Facebook at work" is not.

Comment: Really? So you think it is ok for your boss to put your work contract and your employee file on a websiote for everyone to read? Including reprimands, payslips, raises and all the things HR collects?

Comment: Here is one from the UK I think... https://www.yourerc.com/blog/post/What-HR-Needs-to-Keep-Confidential.aspx

Comment: I don't see anything from the OP about putting that information online.  I agree that would be wrong, but I see no indication it has happened.

Comment: it is no difference. He is not supposed to share it. Putting it online is just the most public form, but for the case - any sharing is sharing if confidential information.

Comment: There is literally *no mention of anything being posted online* in the original question, let alone anything confidential.  Are you sure you posted this answer on the correct question?  I honestly don't know where you're getting this from.

Comment: From the comment of one logically failing steve-o who seems to think that the information is not confidential. Non confidential information can, logical conclusion, be shared online.

Comment: You are going down a slippery slope from "it is wrong to share confidential details online with random strangers" to "it is wrong to share non-confidential details with the employee's parents". It is also not clear how you conclude that this sharing was *illegal*, when the OP hasn't mentioned what exactly was shared. Also, given that there are about 180 countries in the world, a grand total of 1 country doesn't quite fit the definition of "most countries".

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to not respond in any way. Sure, you're parents may keep asking questions. Just limit it to one word answers so you're not being disrespectful.

In no way can you let your employer know that this is the way to handle you at work. It won't make things better.

Have a grown up conversation with your boss that you prefer to be dealt with directly if there is a problem. That's it. You can't make him do it. Don't go into details about how it makes you feel or what it does to the relationship with your parents. It's none of your boss's business. Which is the entire point.

To keep your sanity, just keep imagining the look on your boss's face when you tell him you got a new job.